# Changing background image of selected CSS Tab linked to radio

Tags: html, css, web, tabs

I am trying to use the CSS tabs technique from css-tricks.com and adapting it to me needs.
http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/

I would like to have each tab show it's own background image, and a different background image unique to that tab when the specific tab is selected.

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">                  
    <div class="productTab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabgroup1" checked>
       <label for="tab1" id="productTabLabel1">Tab One</label>   
       <div class="productTabContent">
           stuff0
       </div> 
    </div>  
    <div class="productTab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabgroup1">
       <label for="tab2" id="productTabLabel2">Tab Two</label>     
       <div class="productTabContent">
           stuff1
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    min-height:200px;
    clear: both;
}

.productTab {
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 164px;
}

.productTab [type=radio] {
    display: none;   
}

.productTab label{
    /*background: #eee;*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px; 
    margin-left: -1px; 

}

.productTabContent {
    background: #229FE8;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*Changes the style of the selected Label and brings it to the front*/
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

/*Brings the content adjacent to the label to the front*/
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .productTabContent {
  z-index: 1;
}

#productTabLabel1 {
    background-image: url('../img/products1.jpg');
}

#productTabLabel2 {
    background-image: url('../img/products2.jpg');
}
```

Another issue I am having is that the labels are not growing to show the background image even when I specify their dimensions although it's probably something obvious I will realise later.

Comment: In this case, I do think that a JSfiddle.net example **with** actual linked images would be of benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding on your part as to what actual forms the 'tab'.

It's not the `label`...it's the div with a class of `.productTab`.

I've cleared out a little of the extra CSS and changed some colors so you can see what is going on.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4MF3/2/)

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    min-height:200px;
    clear: both;
}

.productTab {
    float: left;
    width: 132px;
    height: 164px;
    //background-color: red;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
}

.productTab [type=radio] {
    display: none;   
}

.productTab label{
    /*background: #eee;*/
    //border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    position: relative;
    left: 1px; 
    margin-left: -1px;

}

.productTabContent {
    background: #229FE8;
    //border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*Changes the style of the selected Label and brings it to the front*/
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  //background: white;
  //border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

/*Brings the content adjacent to the label to the front*/
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .productTabContent {
  z-index: 1;
}

.productTabLabel1 {
    //background-image: url('../img/products1.jpg');
    background-color: #bada55;
}

.productTabLabel2 {
    //background-image: url('../img/products2.jpg');
    background-color: #663399;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! figured it out, answered my question, getting rid of the productTabContent background made it very clear.